# org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47))

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I have a file that contains a HashMap customer list in json format.

Like this:

```
{"Davide":{"name":"Davide","cf":"FRCDVD","pi":"1234",
    "telephone":"333","website":"www","sector":"Student","address":"Rome"}}
```

This is just a one customer of list. 
Everytime the controller is called I want to take datas from the file and convert them into HashMap list.

I tried to do this with:

```
HashMap<String, Customer> listCustomer = new HashMap<>();
listCustomer = new ObjectMapper().readValue(pathCustomerFile, HashMap.class); //This line gives me error
```

I got this error:

> org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)

How can I do that?

Comment: read this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1394. maybe it will be useful

Comment: May be `pathCustomerFile` is a String? 

I had a similar problem, I was wrong with the input parameter. Fixed by replacing with `new File (pathCustomerFile)`

Answer (score 28):

I had this issue recently. I was trying to pass a path (in the form of a string) to readValue. You need to pass it either a string to parse, or a file object. Based on your variable nameI think you may have passed it the path to a file.

(Basically, it's reading the '/' in the file path and throwing errors on them.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this was exactly as @Sergey K pointed out in the earliest comments. So the credit goes to him.

```
String pathCustomerFile = "/blah/blah.json";  // <-- Problematic line
listCustomer = new ObjectMapper().readValue(pathCustomerFile, HashMap.class);
```

Turns out `pathCustomerFile` was `String` and jackson runtime was trying to interpret the value of this string as a JSON object, hence the error.

**Unexpected character '/'** is the very first character of the path value `"/blah/blah.json"`

You can also tell this by the checked exception that the `readValue` method throws, if it is `ProcessingException`, then chances are the parameter itself is going to be interpreted as the JSON string.

**SOLUTION:**

Wrapping the path string with `File` resolves the problem:

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File(pathCustomerFile), HashMap.class);
```

You can verify this by the checked exception being thrown changing to `IOException` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please double check your input JSON string you don't have it wrongly escaped or `/` dangling somewhere. For example `/\"name\"`. Then Provide the correct type mapping tis way:

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(pathCustomerFile, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Customer>>(){});
```

My answer was tested with jackson-mapper-asl 1.9.13.

** Your mapping just with `HashMap.class` will not give you desired results as Jackson will map your JSON into `Map<String, Map>`. You will find out, when you will try to get a value from Map and operate as if it were type of Customer.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a POJO for customers having the list with the customers and the getter/setter pair, like that:

```
class CustomersFile{
  List<Customer> customers;

  //getter and setter
}
```

Then I would create class Customer with the field name and customerDetails, like that:

```
class Customer {
  String name;
  CustomerDetails details;

  //getters and setters for both fields
}
```

And finally I would create the class CustomerDetails with all the fields, like that:

```
class CustomerDetails {
  String name;
  String telephone;
  int pi; // and so on

  //getters and setters for all fields  
}
```

Then using object mapper I would map all the customers from json to my CustomersFile object:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//this configuration is needed in case you have only one customer in your json.
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
CustomersFile customersFile = mapper.readValue(pathCustomerFile, CustomersFile.class);
```

To access the list of customers, just call:

```
List<Customer> customers = customersFile.getCustomers();
```

If you really need a HashMap then loop through the list and fill this hash map:

```
HashMap<String, Customer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Customer customer : customers) {
  // as string you can use the id of the customer (pi) but its no necessary, just use your desired String
  map.put("String.valueOf(customer.getPi())", customer);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Below are the dependencies I use in my project's pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

**Error**:
no suitable method found for configure(DeserializationFeature,boolean)

Comment: what version of jackson do you use?

Comment: gson 2.3.1, jackson-mapper-asl 1.9.13

Comment: @DavideFruci see my UPDATE, also try it without configuring the mapper to accept the single value as array

Comment: I added your dependecies but I have the same error again.

Comment: Try to use 'objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);'

Comment: mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true); **error** no suitable method found for configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.boolean);

---

Like dependecies I have: jackson-annotations (2.4.1), jackson-core (2.4.1), jackson-databind (2.4.1), json (20090211) and jackson-mapper-asl (1.9.13)

Comment: In the end I converted file json in string and then this string in HashMap using: **mapCustomer = mapper.readValue(jsonString,
                    new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Customer>>() {
                    });**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was mistakenly sending comments in my request payload like '//'.
Removing '//' worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I add comments in JSON.
I find solution on https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1394

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);
final HashMap<String, Customer> listCustomer = mapper.readValue(pathCustomerFile, HashMap.class); //This line gives me no error
```